# HTML/CSS - Change button to point in oposite direction

Tags: html, css, button

I have this awesome button from the Internet, which has a feature to display an arrow facing to the right. Now, I have another button, which goes to a previous page, so common sense would say that the arrow on the button should point to the left.

So I changed all the values which have to do with right-animation to a value for a left-animation, but it doesn't quite work.

I don't understand this quite enough, that's why I'm asking if someone with a better understanding of this can help me out.

```css
.button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f4511e;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 200px;
}
.button > span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.button > span:after {
  content: ' »';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.button:hover > span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}
.button:hover > span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class='button'><span>Back</span>
</button>
<button class='button'><span>Again</span>
</button>
```

I have this CSS in a `common.css` which defines a 'standard' button, and in the stylesheets of the page where this HTML is found, it changes some of the CSS (so here the change for my problem must be made) to fit the page's need.

CSS:

```
li:last-child .button {
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding: 13px;
}
```

If anyone could help me out here , I'd be very pleased.

Cheers'

**EDIT:**

The `.button` in the `common.css` has also an width property.

Comment: As I'm working with two different stylesheets, the first mentioned CSS will get applied, no matter what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```css
.button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f4511e;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}
.button > span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.forward > span:after {
  content: ' »';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.back > span:after {
  content: '« ';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.forward:hover > span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}
.back:hover > span {
  padding-left: 25px;
}
.forward:hover > span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
.back:hover > span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <button class='button back'><span>Back</span>
  </button>
  <button class='button forward'><span>Again</span>
  </button>
</body>

</html>
```

Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L04y8m9e/

As an alternative, if you really really need to keep the original css, then the solution would be to change the class of the back button from "button" to "backbutton" so that the standard button css does not apply and then copy all the button styles to new "backbutton" styles making the necessary changes.

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vg0oLuLh/

New version of html:

```
<button class='backbutton'><span>Back</span></button>
<button class='button'><span>Again</span></button>
```

New css to add (the old css remains unchanged):

```
.backbutton {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f4511e;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 200px;
}

.backbutton > span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.backbutton > span:after {
  content: '« ';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.backbutton:hover > span {
  padding-left: 25px;
}
.backbutton:hover > span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey, @J-van-Amerongen, you first set my answer as the correct solution but then reverted that. Is there still something that you are missing or that is not working for you?

Comment: As I'm working with two different stylesheets, the first mentioned CSS will get applied, no matter what. So when I use your code, it doesn't work at all, as the `.back` button doe not respond on hover and the `.forward` just moves

Comment: In this case, maybe just change the css class in the html. Remove the "button" class from all back buttons, and then just add whatever is missing to the css definition of the "back" class.

Comment: Yeah, maybe it is much easier to abandon the `common.css` all together

Comment: It seems to be cleaner to abandon it. You could then define the generic button css styles for all buttons. And separately add the forward and back functionalities explicitly. This would give your styles some nice structure and separation. With the current common.css you are basically saying that every button should have the right arrow which may not be true to all your buttons.

Comment: @JvanAmerongen, I added an alternative approach to my answer and also a new jsfiddle. This approach assumes that you keep the old css and add new one. However, you need to change the class of one of the buttons. Let me know if that works for you. The drawback of this is that you have css code repetition.

Comment: I've abandoned the `common.css` and combined all the common CSS of the two buttons, where the CSS differs, I used :nth-type-of(1 or 2), which all seems to work!

Answer (score 1):

Here is your fixed code:

```
.button {
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #f4511e;
    border: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 28px;
    padding: 20px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 5px;
 }
 .button > span {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.buttonAgain > span:after {
    content: ' »';
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: -20px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.buttonBack > span:before {
    content: '« ';
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: -70px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.buttonAgain:hover > span {
    padding-right: 25px;
}
.buttonBack:hover > span {
    padding-left: 25px;
}
.buttonAgain:hover > span:after {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 0;
}

.buttonBack:hover > span:before {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 0;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9w6fzabn/)

Comment: I've edited my code with a `width` property, but now when I run your code, the arrow is stationary and when I leave the button, the arrow does it's animation on the far left side (which the normal button does not)

Comment: Can you give me a JSFiddle for the problem? :) I'll try to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS3 `transform` property. Play around with the `rotate(Xdeg)` value.

For more information regarding this property, you can check its details on http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp, or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform.

Comment: This isn't quite what I meant, as this also rotates the text inside the `<button>` and the `<span>`

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean, give me a min and I'll get you what you need :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi ive edited your code and got something like this:

```
.button:first-child > span {
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
transition: 0.5s;
}
.button:first-child > span:before {
content: '» ';
position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
top: 0;
left: -20px;
transition: 0.5s;
}
.button:first-child:hover > span {
padding-left: 25px;
}
.button:first-child:hover > span:before {
opacity: 1;
left: 0;
}
```

here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/xde9046k/2/

Comment: When I hover the `back` button, an arrow pointing to the left appears

Answer (score 0):

Check this..

HTML:

```
<button class='button'><span>Back</span></button>
<button class='button'><span>Again</span></button>
```

CSS:

```
.button {
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #f4511e;
    border: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 28px;
    padding: 20px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 5px;
 }
 .button > span {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.button > span:before {
    content: ' <<';
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0;
    left:-10px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.button:hover > span {
    padding-left: 25px;
}
.button:hover > span:before {
    opacity: 1;
    left: -10px;
}
```